# How do you tile an image in a checkerboard fashion on GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm currently trying to make a background in which an image is tiled (checkerboard style) across a white background. How should one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy \ paste and repeat. It'll get increasingly faster as you go and no matter how large the image it'll fill up quickly.

[image]

A variation on this idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem

Comment: You only need to build a 2x2 version. If you copy that, you can use it as a pattern  then.

Answer (score 1):

- `Filter > Decor > Add Border`

  - set `Border X size` to half the width of your image
  - set `Border Y size` to half the height of your image
  - change `Border color` to white
  - set `Delta value on color` to 1
- `Filter > Map > Make Seamless`
- `Filter > Map > Tile`